# Kohana 3 Custom Filter Valid PHP callback?

Tags: filter, callback, validation, kohana-3

Is it possible to use a function as a custom filter? For example, instead of:

```
$validate->filter('myfield', 'trim');
```

If I try to do:

```
$validate->filter('myfield', 'myfunc');
```

It will say Function myfunc does not exist.
I noticed the second param for filter is supposed to be a "valid PHP callback", so do I need to do anything special with my own function?

Answer (score 0):

you must create `myfunc($value)` function, which will return a filtered value. Also you can put additional params:

```
$validate->filter('myfield', 'myfunc', array(1, 'two'));

function myfunc($value, $param1, $param2) 
{   
   // $param1 == 1   
   // $param2 == 'two';   
   return $value; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work, but only by putting it either inside my validation function or inside my controller action. So     public function validate() { function myfunc($value) {} } Is that where it's supposed to go? Seems a bit weird to put it there, I didn't know you put functions inside other functions hah.

Comment: myfunc() is a single function, defined in your app. Not in controller, not in any other function.

Comment: Where do you mean when you say "defined in your app"? I think the problem is that the function needs to be defined before it's called so that's why at first it said function not found. So where exactly is the best place to put these kind of functions? It's currently in my bootstrap... but I'm sure that's not a good place for it.

Comment: Forgot to say that this filter function is only used for the admin side so putting them in bootstrap also loads them for regular users.

Comment: Ok I think I found a better place to put the functions. In my admin model I put the functions in my public function __construct(), but this is still inside a function which you said it shouldn't be. Anyone know where they should go then?

Comment: Validation occurs in your model. Any custom validation methods should be kept in the same model. The method need to be static in your model and references as 'Model_MyModel::myfunc'. If you're using validation methods over different models you might either want to create a base class or create a special model class just to keep validation methods. Do not put global stuff in your bootstrap.